# Filter Reference Entity Data in JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jakarta-ee, jpa-2.0

As per the requirement i need to maintain back references of each data so I am not updating the actual row in db i am creating a new row in db with active status true and change the older row status to false.

```
User:
Name   | Status
XYZ    | 1
```

Now anybody update this row so now my db like:

```
Name   | Status
XYZ    | 0
XYZ1   | 1
```

XYZ1 is updated name of User table.
I am using **JPA** as a **ORM** .I need to figure out how to get only active rows in Entity.

I need help to get filtered data from the reference data only active will reflect everywhere.

Comment: Don't store old versions in the same table. Use Envers to do that for you.

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks but what about back reference if we use hibernate Envers then we can't do that which is the main requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Jpa QL with status=1 in where condition to retrieve the active one.